# return type of async function to return success msg

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following API controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> PostRegister(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"\">link</a>");

            }

        }
//there should be a return value here
}
```

what I want is to return a success message that the user has been added how could that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web API you dont need to return `ActionResult` instead you can return `HttpResponseMessage`

so it will be like this

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRegister(RegisterViewModel model)

//Prepare the response message
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
---
responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
responseMessage.Content = new StringContent("Success: registered.");

return responseMessage;
```